# How to convert tkinter script which uses multiple image resources to .exe | image no such file or directory

Tags: python, tkinter, package, exe, software-distribution

I am trying to create an executable of my script, but running the .exe does not find the image. I have tried both onefile and multiples and pasting the images inside but it does not work.

These would be my images.

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Tai Project")
root.geometry("600x600")
root.resizable(0, 0)
img = PhotoImage(file="Tai_Project\ccc.png")
img_opo = PhotoImage(file="Tai_Project\opo.png")
img_label = PhotoImage(file="Tai_Project\labeltest.png")
```

Comment: If you're using PyInstaller to make your .exe, see [this](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function for all paths:

```
import sys
import os


def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Usage example:

```
img = PhotoImage(file=resource_path("Tai_Project\ccc.png"))
```

Also in your .spec file you need to match directories in "datas" section like this:

```
a.datas += [("Tai_Project\ccc.png","C:\\Users\\username\\projects\\my_project\\Tai_Project\\ccc.png", "DATA")]
```

This way your files will be included in .exe and will be available in TEMP directory which is created when you run your program.

Comment: I have tried to copy my route, in the .spec: 

 a.datas += [("Tai_Project\ccc.png","C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Python1\\Tai_Project\\ccc.png", "DATA")]

But it keeps giving me this error

"C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI199162\Tai_Project\ccc.png": no such file or directory

Comment: So have you replaced all paths to resource_path(path) calls?

Comment: So first thing is to include your files in exe file. It is done by this spec file.
When you run your program (exe file) it creates some folder structure that is defined in spec file under user's TEMP directory.
So program should look for files in some TEMP directory instead of your usual paths.
Funtion that I shared allows you to convert this paths.

Comment: I edit the post with the modifications and the same error, I am putting something wrong

Comment: First thing - replace single backslashes to double backslashes as you need to escape backslash symbol. Second thing - can you pls check contents of temp directory which is created when you run your program? Do you have Tai_Project dir there?

Comment: You can put console=True in your spec and print resource_path("Tai_Project\ccc.png") to find this dir

Comment: No, it's not inside

Comment: C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Python1\Tai_Project\ccc.png

This is the print in python console

Comment: Are you running this print executing EXE file after building?

Comment: it must be something like C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI12345\Tai_Project\ccc.png

Comment: When i executing the .exe i have this directory: C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI46802\Tai_Project\ccc.png

But in theprint on python console with resource_path("Tai_Project\ccc.png")

I have this one : C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Python1\Tai_Project\ccc.png

Comment: And error message refers to Desktop\Python1 directory? Not temporary one?

Comment: The error message is: C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI46802\Tai_Project\ccc.png.  

But the final path ends in C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI46802, "Tai_Project is not inside"

Comment: As I can see in your other question you had error '_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI88482\Tai_Project\ccc.png": no such file or directory'. This directory is result of resource_path function that is executed from EXE file. So in this directory you should have your files if you configured .spec correctly

Comment: "Tai_Project is not inside" then you need to check .spec file again. Can you provide latest .spec file contents?

Comment: Done, you can see how is actually the .spec

Comment: ok. I can see in datas you have same path for all three tuples, you can change it to corresponding names:     datas=[("Tai_Project\\ccc.png","C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Python1\\Tai_Project\\ccc.png", "DATA"), ("Tai_Project\\odo.png","C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Python1\\Tai_Project\\odo.png", "DATA"), ("Tai_Project\\labeltest.png","C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Python1\\Tai_Project\\labeltest.png", "DATA")],
But I think it is not the issue. Then you need to dig into build logs. Can you upload them?

Comment: I've uploaded it under the specs, if that's what you mean with build logs

Comment: @Magethepunisher is it possible to share this project? Is it on github or something?

Comment: Hi dude. Actually I solved the error. I add Doble \\ and complete path in the resource_path. `img = PhotoImage(file=resource_path("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Python1\\Tai_Project\\ccc.png"))` -This solve the problem, now I can execute the .exe without error. But thanks a lot for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually .spec

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['Tai_Interface.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[("Tai_Project\\ccc.png","C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Python1\\Tai_Project\\ccc.png", "DATA"), ("Tai_Project\\ccc.png","C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Python1\\Tai_Project\\odo.png", "DATA"), ("Tai_Project\\ccc.png","C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Python1\\Tai_Project\\labeltest.png", "DATA")],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)


pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='Tai_Interface',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tai_Interface.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4064, in __init__
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4009, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Python1\Tai_Project\dist\Tai_Interface.exe\Tai_Project\ccc.png": no such file or directory
```